# Linux Centos 7 Convert upstart script into systemd service

Tags: systemd, upstart

I have the upstart script below, how can I translate it into a systemd service ?

```
description "x11vnc"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

#console log

respawn
respawn limit 20 5

exec /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
```

Comment: Really recommend you read the tutorial of systemd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the configuration options of an upstart configuration can be translated directly into systemd unit directives. That's the case for `description` (which becomes [`Description=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description=)) and `exec` (which becomes [`ExecStart=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=).)

The upstart configuration doesn't have an `expect fork` or `daemon` stanza (which would translate into `Type=forking`), so we should use `Type=simple` for our systemd unit.

Let's take a look at the remaining stanzas:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]
```

This is essentially just saying this service should start when the machine boots and stop when it shuts down. In systemd, this is done by installing it and linking it to `multi-user.target`. See the `[Install]` section on the final unit.

```
#console log
```

This is commented out... But you could control similar configuration from a systemd unit using [`StandardOutput=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#StandardOutput=) and related options.

In upstart, `console logged` is the default and it somewhat matches the systemd default of sending output to the journal (since the journal is the main logger in systemd world.)

```
respawn
respawn limit 20 5
```

So the first line asks that the service should be restarted *if it ends unexpectedly*, which I believe would translate to [`Restart=on-failure`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Restart=), though it is possible that `Restart=yes` (always restart) is closer to what upstart does here (I don't know enough upstart to tell exactly which it does.)

The second line indicates the limits, respawn at most 20 times in 5 seconds, which in systemd you would configure with [`StartLimitBurst=20` and `StartLimitIntervalSec=5`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#StartLimitIntervalSec=interval).

Finally, putting it all together, you get this in your `/etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc
StartLimitBurst=20
StartLimitIntervalSec=5

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /root/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After creating this file, execute `systemctl daemon-reload` for systemd to load the unit file. Then `systemctl start x11vnc.service` for it to start running it and `systemctl enable x11vnc.service` for it to start it on boot.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the very useful explanation.

Comment: Happy to help! If it doesn't work for you, post more comments, I'm happy to try to fix anything if anything is not working as expected. Thanks!